# How to remove xss_clean in CI3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to CI and had just updated an old app developed by 3rd party developer and as I try to create any new record I get the following error:

```
Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name `Field Name` .(xss_clean)
```

I have read many questions and answers on how to make it work, however, I have also read that this is a bad practice and would therefore like to get rid of `xss_clean` completely, but I just cannot seem to find straightforward information for how to do it.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Show us codes of that

Comment: Look for and remove all references to xss_clean from any validation rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xss_clean is used mainly with CI's form validation library. As stated in the comments, the best way to get rid of this error (if you don't need the features of xss_clean) would be to remove all instances of xss_clean from your validation rules.

Example of where you could find xss_clean in your app:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
```

[codeigniter form validation documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 4):

xss_clean is no longer part of form validation. The alternative is not to use it, as xss_clean is doing sanitization and not validation.

xss_clean is part of security helper. If you need to do it, after validation you do a:

```
$this->load->helper('security');
$value = $this->input->post('formvalue', TRUE); 
// ...where TRUE enables the xss filtering
```

... i think...

Also, you can enable global xss filtering in the config.php file:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

Or if you want to remove then you have to find all xss_clean used in validation and remove.

Comment: $config['global_xss_filtering'] is deprecated